# How to customize and change ready-made CSS libraries such as Twitter Bootstrap, and what other alternatives exist?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I recently learned about [Twitter Bootstrap CSS](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/),  and wonder what other pre-fabricated stylesheets are also available that would facilitate rapid development.

Once I settle on a CSS library, how would I customize and make changes to it?

Comment: Are you talking about http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap? If so, about which PHP class are you talking?

Comment: Are you talking about twitter bootstrap

Comment: Yes....i am talking about that... but want to know is there any other bootstrap css for quick start.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this for form elements https://github.com/derrickpelletier/Bootstrap-PHP-Helper for twitter bootstrap

this is twitter's bootstrap css file https://raw.github.com/twitter/bootstrap/master/bootstrap.css

Twitter Bootstrap style for CakePHP instantly
http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/mxkocak/2011/11/16/twitter_bootstrap_style_for_cakephp_instantly

IMO Another good alternative of twitter Bootstrap are

Foundation - http://foundation.zurb.com/
Easy Front-end-Framework http://easyframework.com/

Have a look at documentation of all Framework and decide which one would be fit in your developing style

Comment: Hi Vyas, i just mean that is there any other bootstrap css available to use and if yes then which one is best...

Comment: @ime.devdesks There is no "best". It depends on you favourite style / design.

Comment: hmm, thanks for your comments. But i think there must be a general style exist for quick start on projects... Which will shrink our time which we'll waste on structuring the layout of a templates.

Answer (score 16):

**Have a look at [Skeleton](http://www.getskeleton.com/) and [HTML Kickstart](http://www.99lime.com/elements/).**

Skeleton is pretty barebone. Twitter itself is using it for their Hogan.js website.

Kickstart has more stuff in it (icons, widgets etc.) but no fluid layout.